# Are these two rotation matrices related?

Tags: rotations, cross-product

There are two $3\times3$ matrices $A$ and $B.$ Both represent a rotation in 3D space. $A$ and $B$ are given as follows where $a,b,c$ are column vectors.

$A = [\begin{array}{ccc}a & b & c \\ \end{array}]$

$B = [\begin{array}{ccc}a & c & -b \\ \end{array}]$

The $3$rd column of each matrix is the cross product of the $1$st and $2$nd column. How are these matrices related if in any way?

Answer (score 3):

Another way we could write that relationship is
$$
B = A \,
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I'm not sure if that fully answers your question though...

Answer (score 2):

If you think about the matrices as linear transformations, you can see what their inverses do without having to compute their entries. Namely, $A^{-1}a=\hat x$, $A^{-1}b=\hat y$, and $A^{-1}c = \hat z$. Similarly, $B^{-1}a=\hat x$, $B^{-1}b=-\hat z$, and $B^{-1}c = \hat y$.

Now you can determine the products $A^{-1}B$ and $B^{-1}A$ by trying out what they do to $\hat x$, $\hat y$, and $\hat z$. Both products should turn out to be $90^\circ$ rotations around  $\hat x$, in opposite directions. Similarly, both $AB^{-1}$ and $BA^{-1}$ are $90^\circ$ rotations around $a$.